# Adding a NULL TINYINT(1) column super slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 37 columns. The table has about 1M rows. When I try adding another column:

```
ALTER TABLE main_catalog ADD match_method TINYINT(1) NULL;
```

It takes a very, very long time to add. Why is this so slow? And is there anything I can do to improve this?

Comment: Is anything else using the table while you’re doing this?

Comment: I'm running it locally and can confirm that no other mysql processes are running.

Comment: I think this is because MySQL rewrites the whole table and all indexes when you add (or drop) a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` on a table with many rows will generally take a while.

One phenomenally useful tool for doing an `ALTER TABLE` without locking the table for minutes/hours is [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html), which via some very cool trickery with a copy of the table and some triggers, allows you to do an `ALTER TABLE` with no impact on your users.

Comment: @David542: A couple of additional tools:
[oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html) and Facebook's [online schema change for MySQL](http://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/online-schema-change-for-mysql/430801045932).

Comment: @wchiquito Those are great, I hadn't seen them. +1!

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Why, out of curiosity does the `ALTER TABLE` take so long with not that many rows?

Comment: @David542 It's copying all the data and rebuilding all the indexes. 1M rows is enough that that'll take a while, especially if you have a lot of indexes.